# Find global ordering from local ordering

Tags: python, graph-theory

Suppose you have a list of tuples

```
[(a,d), (a,c), (b,c), (a,b), (c,d)]
```

with the second element of a tuple greater that the first

assume there is only one ordered list (containing all the elements that show up in at least one tuple) consistent will all tuples.  In this case the list

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

How do we find the list?

Comment: That's called *topological sorting* - you should be able to find various examples and modules given that search term.

Comment: Yes, the list must contain all the elements that appear in the tuples, and the ordering given by the list must be consistent with the tuples ( so if tuple (y,x) is in the list of tuples, x must come after y in the final list

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest case, your objects are instances of a class in which methods `__eq__`, `__hash__` and `__lt__` are defined. The first two methods allow you to use `set` while the third method allows you to use `sorted`. Here is an example (`lst` is your initial list of tuples):

```
sorted_elements = sorted({el for t in lst for el in t})
```

You can use the previous solution with numbers and chars (this is just an example):

```
>>> lst = [(3,4), (7,8), (7,9), (1,3)]
>>> sorted_elements = sorted({el for t in lst for el in t})
>>> sorted_elements
[1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

```
>>> lst = [('a','b'), ('c','e'), ('c','z')]
>>> sorted_elements = sorted({el for t in lst for el in t})
>>> sorted_elements
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'z']
```

In a more general case, you might want to use topological sorting (for example, by using the `networkx` package). In this case your objects are of type `A`:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(lst)

sorted_elements = list(nx.topological_sort(G))
```

Here is an example:

```
import networkx as nx

class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

a, b, c, d = A('a'), A('b'), A('c'), A('d')
lst = [(a,d), (a,c), (b,c), (a,b), (c,d)]

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(lst)

sorted_elements = list(nx.topological_sort(G))

print([el.name for el in sorted_elements]) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Your first example does no fulfil the criterion that there us  only one list (ordering) that is consistent with the turple.  [1,3,4,7.8,9] works but so does [7,8,9,1,3,4]  There is no other information about the ordering of the elements that is given in the list of tuples.

Comment: @William You're right, but my code works anyway, even if there is only one such ordering :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jason Harper who noted that the problem is known as topological sorting.

The module graphlib (requires python3) does this.  However, you have to get graphlib-backport

```
        pip3 uninstall graphlib
        pip3 install graphlib-backport
```

Before I did this I had a very old version of graphlib

```
from graphlib import TopologicalSorter
  
# creating an instance of TopologicalSorter
# initial graph is optional
ts = TopologicalSorter()
  
ts.add('d','a')
ts.add('c','a')
ts.add('c','b')
ts.add('b','a')
ts.add('d','c')
print([*ts.static_order()])


#Output
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```